# Inserting an event with the nodejs google calendar API returns 400: "Missing end time"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to insert events via the Google Calendar API with a service account. The goal is to have one calendar that all users view: a server-to-server setup.

As of now, I can properly call the calendar API and list the events on said calendar:

```
var moment = require("moment"),
    googleapis = require("googleapis"),
    googleCal = googleapis.calendar("v3");
    serviceEmail = "********@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    serviceKeyFile = "./key.pem";

var authClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
        serviceEmail,
        serviceKeyFile,
        null,
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
    );

authClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        googleCal.events.list({
            auth: authClient,
            calendarId: "********@gmail.com",
            fields: {
                items: ["end","start","summary"]
            }
        }, function (err, CL) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(CL);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

This properly returns a JSON object that lists all the different objects on the calendar. However, when I try to insert an event directly below the `googleCal.events.list` call:

```
googleCal.events.insert({
    auth: authClient,
    calendarId: "primary",
    resources: {
        start: {
          dateTime: "2014-07-23T18:25:00.000-07:00",
          timeZone: "America/New_York"
        }, 
        end: {
          dateTime: "2014-07-23T19:25:00.000-07:00",
          timeZone: "America/New_York"
        }, 
        summary: "winning @ life",
        description: "winning @ life description"
    }
}, function (err, something) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(something);
        // do something else
    }
})
```

The following `400` is returned:

```
{ errors: 
    [ { domain: 'global',
        reason: 'required',
        message: 'Missing end time.' } ],
  code: 400,
  message: 'Missing end time.'}
```

How do I go about fixing this? The authorization is clearly working—I know because I've used up my unauthorized requests for the day and because I can list all the events. I have also specified an `endTime`. Why is the google calendar API telling me that I haven't?

Comment: As it turns out, I misspelled `resource`. In the above code, I used `resources`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in the keyword "resources" on line 4 of your second snippet. Based on the documentation, it should be a "resource":

```
 * @param  {object} params.resource - Request body data
```