# Create all-day event in Google Calendar via API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create an event in a Google Calendar via the API.
The event should be **all day**, from '2016-03-04' to '2016-03-05'.

Here is the hash that I am sending in the POST body:

```
{
  "summary"     => "MyEvent", 
  "description" => "Just a Test", 
  "start"       => { "date" => "2016-03-04" }, 
  "end"         => { "date" => "2016-03-05" }, 
  "attendees"   => []
}
```

The response is a 400 error, stating `Missing end time.` as the error.

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) it says:

```
end.date    date    The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
```

What am I missing here? How can I create events without explicit times?

Comment: Have you tried reading this stack overflow tickets? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918629/inserting-an-event-with-the-nodejs-google-calendar-api-returns-400-missing-end / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555019/google-calendar-api-update-missing-end-time

Comment: @d.datul1990 I actually did and especially the first one should have brought me to the right path: that sending an empty body results in a rather unhelpful `Missing end time` error. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.
I was actually **not posting the event at all**, the whole request body was a `true` (due to a stupid programming mistake).

The error the Google API sends back is quite misleading, since I did not even send a valid JSON hash.

When I actually **do** send the hash from my question, everything works fine and **an end time is not needed**.